# Magento 2 Possible to make Stock Status working for storeviews?

Tags: magento2, stock-status

In Magento, Stock Status is global, so when a product is **Out-Of-Stock**, then it's disabled for all websites / storeviews.

Are there anyways to make Stock Status working on **storeview** level? I have bought the *Advanced Inventory module* from *Wyomind*, but it only allows you to created different warehouses for different storeviews. And when a warehouse having 0 on the stock, it won't disable the product for that website the warehouse is associated with.

Can I make my own module to have Stock Status working on storeviews? or are there extensions available for this?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3 comes up with new MSI feature, so now you can maintain stock status based on store views. [Check the release notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.0OpenSource.html)

and upgrade your magento 2.x to 2.3